# Is Hyde (Python) a stand alone solution?

Tags: python, hyde

According to the [Hyde website](http://ringce.com/hyde), Hyde is based on the Django template engine. I don't want to install Django and Hype. So, a yes/no question: Is it a stand alone solution?

Comment: I am voting for closing this because the solution was just a download away.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why you don't want to install django?

Comment: @heltonbiker, I just want to keep the whole thing as simple as possible. I'm investigating Wordpress-->static HTML, saw a reference to Hyde and looked into that. Wordpress requires LAMP so I already have that in place. Not afraid to install thing and try.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran, I asked the question because it was not in the documentation, which is where it should be. Not in the download.

Comment: @GUIJunkie, I see. But when it wrote it for a particular package (django), it is implicit that they assume you have it installed. I can provide you  standalone python script, but I would assume that you will have to need python installed.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran, thanks for the offer, but I rolled out my own txt-->html template solution in Python. Works for me. But I want to empower my wife to edit the txt files and that's why I'm looking into CMS solutions. They should be dead simple.

Comment: This **[BLOG][1]** may help. **Getting started with HYDE**


  [1]: http://softvar.github.io/blog/Getting_started_with_hyde.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a standalone solution. You need to have django,pyYAML, markdown installed as pre-requisite.

Comment: This BLOG- http://softvar.github.io/blog/Getting_started_with_hyde.html may help. **Getting started with HYDE**

Answer (score 2):

> Hyde is a static website generator powered by Python & Django

That answers your question.

Comment: This BLOG- **http://softvar.github.io/blog/Getting_started_with_hyde.html** may help. **Getting started with HYDE**